# Angular 8/ ionic 4/ Socket.io - cannot connect to local host server

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io

this is one is very very aggravating. I cannot connect to my local host socket io server after compiling and running on a device. *HOWEVER* I can connect if I launch it through a browser...

so to recap:

`$ ionic serve` will launch on my browser and I connect to the socketio server running on localhost port 8080

`$ ionic cordova run android --device --livereload` gives the error:

> zone-evergreen.js:2952 GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MyU0Jo6 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

thusly I am unable to connect to localhost running on port 8080.
Between launching on my browser or device I change no connection

#### index.html

```html
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

#### app.module.ts

[ngx-socket-io](https://github.com/rodgc/ngx-socket-io)

```js
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'localhost:8080', options: { secure: true } };

@ngModule({
  imports: [
      SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
  ]
})
```

### server

```js
  require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' });
  const app = require('express')();
  const PORT = process.env.CHAT_PORT || 8080;
  const server = require('http').createServer(app);
  const io = require('socket.io')(server);

  server.listen(PORT, (): void => console.log('listening', PORT));

  io.on('connection', socket => console.log('connected'));
```

if there is any other information you need let me know and I'll update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I think is happening:

When you are running **ionic serve** on your PC, your **index.html** code points at the same local PC's running "web server" (points at "self" basically):

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

When you are running live reload, the index.html is run on your mobile device attempting to point at..."localhost" (self again) which is NOT your PC but your mobile device, which is not running socket.io...

To fix you need to serve socket.io from your PC but your code should point at your PC via absolute address (not via localhost). For example if your local PC has local network address of 192.168.0.5 -> you should point the init code to that address and ensure your mobile device when connected to the same network has its own 192.168.0.X address.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: .... oh man.... you are completely correct. I completely forgot about this. when I first set it up, before the server, I have to use the IP address of my laptop! hahah oh man what a long day it has been! thanks a lot I feel dumb as I should have known this!

Comment: no worries;) yeah it’s quite tricky and i faced the same once!